# How to find list of events using Debugger (VS Professional 2012)?

Tags: c#, wpf, debugging, events, visual-studio-2012

Okay, I can't find any help for my question and stackoverflow doesn't seem to have anything either, or I didn't know how to look for it (please correct me, if I'm wrong and I will close this question).

In my program, I have a `Grid` which has a few events definded in code:

```
public Grid _grid = new Grid();
_grid.MouseLeftButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(MyMethod);
//and a few more events...
```

Now during my program run, I saw some weird behaviour that can only come from some events, so I set a breakpoint and stopped the program to use the debugger.

Is there a list I can find somewhere that lists all the currently defined events of the member `_grid` so I can check that no unwanted events have not yet been removed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update 2**

Unfortunately, most events in WPF (i.e. on `UIElement`) are implemented by manually implementing `add`/`remove` which means the event member can only be on the left hand side of a `-=` or `+=` operator (i.e. it can't be "read").  The internals are such that each event is "delegated" to a collection of events and that collection only contains elements for assigned events (e.g. if there's a single `MouseLeftButtonDownEvent += somehandler;` then that collection of events will have only one entry.  Unfortunately, what the collection of events stores to represent a handler is an internal structure that you would have to be able to instantiate to query the collection.  You are unable to instantiate an instance of that structure (`RoutedEventHandlerInfo`, FWIW) in order to query the collection (`UIElement.EventHandlersStore._entries`, also FWIW).  e.g. if you could you, you could query the handler for a particular event as such in the QuickWatch window:

```
grid.EventHandlersStore._entries[
    new RoutedEventHandlerInfo(UIElement.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent, false)]
```

But, the debugger does not allow you to invoke an internal constructor.

There isn't something that lists *just* the events.  You can see all the members of a instance in the debugger (watch, quickwatch, etc.) and the events have a distinct icon.  You can then expand each one of these to see what method was assigned to the event.  For example:

[image]

As you can see, `MyEvent` has been "assigned" the method `t_MyEvent` for this particular instance.

**Update:**
If you have more than one event handler assigned to an event, the debugger will only show the last assigned method in top-level of the event in quick watch.  To see *all* the methods assigned, you'll need to drill-down to the invocation list.  For example:

[image]

.. this shows that both `t_MyEvent` and `t_MyEvent2` are in the invocation list for `MyEvent`.  If you hace no handlers, the value for `MyEvent` will be `null`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So in my example, I should be able to see "MouseLeftButtonDown" somewhere when I expand "_grid"? I am looking in the "Locals"-window, but I cannot see anything...

Comment: Possibly you have multiple delegates assigned to the event, I've updated the answer to include that...

Comment: In my program I have only one method assigned to each event, but a few methods in total that use e.g. `MouseButtonEventHandler`. I was looking for invocationList but cannot find it.
Would you kindly show your example for a WPF `Grid`? Maybe it is a bit different there.

Comment: Just for a temp. info: I need to leave for a couple of hours and will not be available to answer and comment if needed asap, when I'm back.