# Is there a way to see how many methods are added to an event in the VS2013 debugger?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, debugging

I'm confused about the answer to this Stack Overflow question:
[How to find list of events using Debugger (VS Professional 2012)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14839050/how-to-find-list-of-events-using-debugger-vs-professional-2012)

I was reverse-engineering some code that included this line:

```
IsVisibleChanged += delegate { UpdateReallyLoopRendering(); };
```

... where IsVisibleChanged is UIElement:

```
public event DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler IsVisibleChanged
```

I was concerned about how many methods had been added to its invocation list and that some of them might be duplicates so I wanted a way to see what, or at least how many, items there were in its invocation list in the debugger.   The answer to the above S.O. question shows an example of doing this in a QuickWatch window, but then the text around that is crossed-out, but still present.  And the non-crossed out part of the answer seems to say it can't be done.

So **IS** there a way to see, or at least get a count of, the items in the invocation list for IsVisibleChanged?

**EDIT:** This question was flagged as a duplicate of [C# Know how many EventHandlers are set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439621/c-sharp-know-how-many-eventhandlers-are-set)  but I don't see how that's a duplicate because

A: my question is about a Microsoft UIElement

B: my question is how to do it in the debugger

Comment: How is it a duplicate? The "this question already has an answer" example is for an event handler of one's own making - how do I apply it to a **UIElement**? Also N.B. that my question is how to do this in the **debugger**.

Answer (score 0):

You can Delegate.GetInvocationList() method. See sample code below:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.Click += Click_1;
        t.CheckInvocationList();
    }

    private static void Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e) {}
}

public class Test
{
    public event EventHandler Click;

    public void CheckInvocationList()
    {
        var t = Click;
        if(t != null) 
        {
            var methods = t.GetInvocationList();
            Console.WriteLine(methods.Length); // Output = 1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I apply your suggestion to my case? If I try to do a _IsVisibleChanged.GetInvocationList()_ the compiler points out that IsVisibleChanged can only appear on the left side of a += or -=.